# Layout template not working with component

Tags: ember.js

I have template that starts its definition with:

```
App.PasswordInputComponent = Ember.TextField.extend({
    templateName: 'templates/components/text-input-component',
    layoutName: 'templates/components/text-input-layout',
```

Without these two properties set it would pick up the default template for a component which is "templates/components/password-input". What's surprising (read: disappointing) is that it in fact it does load this default AND ignores both parameters!

The documentation states that these two properties are meant to behave the same as for their `View` parent-class but that's not my experience so far. Can anyone tell me if they've got this working?

Comment: from what I can ascertain, the layout method for the component never gets called put a break point in the ember.js file line 20404. and variables this.get(''), layoutName, to see what is classes are calling the layout function http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OCUHESa/32/edit

Answer (score 2):

I found that if you specify:

```
templateName: 'components/text-input-component'
```

you can get the component to use your template named as such, but you also need to refer to the handlebars helper by that name too:

```
{{text-input-component}}
```

rather than:

```
{{password-input}}
```

Not sure why it works this way.

Comment: Wow, really? That's not ideal but let me play around with that.

Answer (score 1):

For those still searching for an answer to this one, here's what I do:

```
App.MyFirstComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    title: 'Hello'
});
```

This will check for a template in `components/my-first`, which would read like so:

```
{{title}} World
```

Then, to extend this component and use the same layout, I do this:

```
App.MySecondComponent = App.MyFirstComponent.extend({
    layoutName: 'components/my-first',
    title: 'Goodbye, Cruel'
});
```

Now, to call both:

```
{{my-first}} // output: Hello World

{{my-second}} // output: Goodbye, Cruel World
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify a `layoutName` on a Component because the block content of the Handlebars helper in interpreted as the template and the template you specify becomes the layout. So there is no option to define the layoutName.

More information in this commit: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/6f6247f54e1f2b841f73dedd274e962b3703ca1d

> In a component the block passed when calling it
>   (in a handlebars template) is interpreted as its template, and a
>   template that was registered as `components/my-component` becomes its
>   layout.

and the API-docs: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ComponentTemplateDeprecation.html